# How to update a data in line from text file

Tags: c#

I have a line in text file with below structure:

```
|Date    |Name  |TotalAcc|Folder|Done
|20190105|LHN888|1       |5     |
|20190105|RLM916|2       |5     |
|20190105|TDE374|1       |5     |
```

I want to update the `"Done"` field to same amount with `"TotalAcc"` field.

I have tried to read all the line and some code but seems like I miss out something.

What is actually happening is that:

```
text = text.Replace(DT11.Done, DT11.TotalAcc);
```

is throwing this exception:

> 'String cannot be of zero length. Parameter name: oldValue'

```
if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\" + strn))
{
    string ori_Files11 = @"C:\Users\var\log\test.txt";
    List<Flds> ListDT11 = new List<Flds>();
    using (StreamReader file11 = new StreamReader(ori_Files11))
    {
        string line;
        string text = "";
        while ((line = file11.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] SpltStr11 = line.Split('|');
            Flds DT11     = new Flds();
            DT11.Date     = SpltStr11[0];
            DT11.Name     = SpltStr11[1];
            DT11.TotalAcc = SpltStr11[2];
            DT11.Folder   = SpltStr11[3];
            DT11.Done     = SpltStr11[4];

            ListDT11.Add(DT11);
         }
    }
    for (int ii = 0; ii < ListDT11.Count(); ii++)
    {
         text = text.Replace(DT11.Done, DT11.TotalAcc);
         File.WriteAllText(ori_Files11, text);                            
    }

 }
```

My expected result is like below:

```
|Date    |Name  |TotalAcc|Folder|Done
|20190105|LHN888|1       |5     |1
|20190105|RLM916|2       |5     |2
|20190105|TDE374|1       |5     |1
```

Comment: I got error : 'String cannot be of zero length.
Parameter name: oldValue'

Comment: The code you give us doesn't compile on it's own either, lots of stuff is missing from the snippet.

Comment: What did you get from your code and what is text?

Comment: What do you expect `text = text.Replace(DT11.Done, DT11.TotalAcc);` to do if `DT11.Done` is blank (empty string)? What does https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_ say will happen if you do that?

Comment: this line give me the error : text = text.Replace(DT11.Done, DT11.TotalAcc);

Comment: Why you don't just assign `DT11.Done = SpltStr11[2];` in the first loop and get rid of the second loop, if they need to be the same?

Comment: `yes that's what i want.` I give you a string containing the words "Hello World" I ask you to change all "" (blank strings) to "Bob". What would you expect to occur, and why?

Answer (score 2):

This is happenning because `String.Replace` takes two string arguments 'oldValue' and 'newValue'. You specified the newValue 'DT11.TotalAcc' however an empty string is not legal for the oldValue.

What you could do is after fetching DT11.Done, replace it with some tempValue and then use this to replace with new value

something like

```
while ((line = file11.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    string[] SpltStr11 = line.Split('|');
    Flds DT11     = new Flds();
    DT11.Date     = SpltStr11[0];
    DT11.Name     = SpltStr11[1];
    DT11.TotalAcc = SpltStr11[2];
    DT11.Folder   = SpltStr11[3];
    DT11.Done     = SpltStr11[4];

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DT11.Done))
    {
         DT11.Done = "tempVal";
    }

    ListDT11.Add(DT11);
 }
```

In this way you will not get the error. Rest of the code you can format accordingly

Comment: DT11.Done     = SpltStr11[2] - could have avoided the if condition and infact, replace as well.

Answer (score 0):

You do not quite require Flds Class for this purpose. Since the Done field is the last line, you can parse totalAcc and append it to end of line, while parsing the file. For example,

```
var data = File.ReadAllText(intputFileName);
var list = data.Split(new[]{Environment.NewLine},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder($"{list.First()}{Environment.NewLine}");

foreach(var line in list.Skip(1))
{
        var totalAcc = line.Split(new[]{"|"},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[2];
        strBuilder.AppendLine($"{line}{totalAcc}");
}

File.WriteAllText(outputFileName,strBuilder.ToString());
```

Output

```
|Date    |Name  |TotalAcc|Folder|Done
|20190105|LHN888|1       |5     |1       
|20190105|RLM916|2       |5     |2       
|20190105|TDE374|1       |5     |1
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently stuff you are doing contains some mistakes. In below line you will get an error.

```
text = text.Replace(DT11.Done, DT11.TotalAcc);
```

Because in the file you have provided value for column *"Done"* is really absent(it is null or empty), that is why it throws an Exception.
Because Replace method takes first argument and replaces it with a value given as second argument. In case it is empty or null it will raise an exception

So you need to change you code as below. Please take into account that I have written code with using you class called *"Flds"*. I do not know why actually you are using it. It can be removed in any case. It does not make sense to use it in this process

```
    private static void SyncAndUpdateFileContent(string fileToSync)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(@"C:\Users\" + fileToSync))
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException($"File {fileToSync} does not exist!");
        }

        var ori_Files11 = @"C:\Users\var\log\test.txt";
        List<Flds> ListDT11 = new List<Flds>();
        string fileHeader = null;
        using (StreamReader file11 = new StreamReader(ori_Files11))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = file11.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //Get file header copy
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(fileHeader))
                {
                    fileHeader = line;
                    continue;
                }

                string[] SpltStr11 = line.Split('|');
                Flds DT11 = new Flds
                {
                    Date = SpltStr11[0],
                    Name = SpltStr11[1],
                    TotalAcc = SpltStr11[2],
                    Folder = SpltStr11[3],
                    Done = SpltStr11[4]
                };

                ListDT11.Add(DT11);
            }
        }

        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder($"{fileHeader}");
        foreach (var listDT11Item in ListDT11.Skip(1))
        {
            stringBuilder.AppendLine($"{listDT11Item.Date}|{listDT11Item.Name}|{listDT11Item.TotalAcc}|{listDT11Item.Folder}|{listDT11Item.TotalAcc}");
        }

        //Just call WriteAllText method at the end
        File.WriteAllText(ori_Files11, stringBuilder.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's compact way of doing this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  // Read all lines from file
  var lines = File.ReadAllLines("Path");
  string[] linesToWrite = new string[lines.Length];
  for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
  {
    var cells = lines[i].Split('|');
    // Appned value in "TotalAcc" column at the end of current line
    // and store it in array of lines, that will be written to file
    linesToWrite[i] = lines[i] + cells[2];
  }
  File.WriteAllLines("path", linesToWrite);
}
```